# How to draw a simple grid using opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to draw a grid that should look something like this:

[image]

but what I get instead:

[image]

*A black screen with two orange lines on the left and bottom borders*

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#define WIDTH 1000
#define HEIGHT 400
#define OFFSET 200

using namespace std;

float x = 0;
float y = 0;

void init (void)
{
    //glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho (0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0, -2.0, 2.0);

    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void drawline (float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
    glBegin (GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f (x1, y1);
    glVertex2f (x2, y2);
    glEnd();
}

void drawgrid()
{
    glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glColor3ub (240, 57, 53);

    for (float i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i += 10)
    {
        if ((int) i % 100 == 0) glLineWidth (3.0);
        else if ((int) i % 50 == 0) glLineWidth (2.0);
        else glLineWidth (1.0);
        drawline (0, i, (float) WIDTH, i);
    }

    for (float i = 0; i < WIDTH; i += 10)
    {
        if ((int) i % 100 == 0) glLineWidth (3.0);
        else if ((int) i % 50 == 0) glLineWidth (2.0);
        else glLineWidth (1.0);
        drawline (i, 0, i, (float) HEIGHT);
    }
}

void display()
{
    drawgrid();

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit (&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize (WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glutCreateWindow ("ECG");

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc (display);
    glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How to make the background white and draw the grid properly?

Comment: There's no reason, in 2015, to use single-buffered rendering anymore. Change `GLUT_SINGLE` to `GLUT_DOUBLE`.

Comment: changed it to `GLUT_DOUBLE` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Why are you using such a tiny (5x5) view frustum (via the `glOrtho()` call) with such large `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT`s?   Heck, your `i` steps are 2x larger than your frustum!

Comment: i'm totaly new to opengl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set up your projection to map the coordinate range [0,5] to the screen. And then, you draw lines at the distance of 10 units, so only the line y=0 is shown.

Actually, the image is implementation specific. You could see the bottom horizontal line, or you could not see it, because you draw not at the bottom pixel center, bot at the bottom border of the bottom pixel row. An implementation might round that away. That is what happened to your left vertical line at x=0.

So you should just set up your `glOrtho` call to match the coordinate range you want to use, and you will see the lines you are drawing.

Use `glClearColor` to change the background color.

Also don't use `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | ...)` in combination with `glutSwapBuffers()`. Either use single buffering, and then there is no buffers to swap, or, as I'd recommend, use double buffering and swap buffers after a frame is finished. Also remove the `glFlush` there, it is not needed if `glutSwapBuffers` is used.

Comment: i changed ortho to `glOrtho (0.0, WIDTH, 0.0, HEIGHT, 0.0, 0.0)` but all i see is two lines in the middle top and middle right joined in the middle like a corner.

Comment: Don't use `0.0, 0.0` as the near and far parameters. `glOrtho` will _fail_ if you set near==far, so you end up with identity matrix, which is indentical to using `glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1)`, so perfectly explains the corner you see. Use `-1.0f, 1.0f` as the last two arguments.

Comment: Perfect, I can see the full grid now except for the top and right borders which i think i should increase the dimensions for that, but the background is black! why is `glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` not working?

Comment: @razzak: Because you forgot to call `glClear()` in the display function, you only did it once during initialization.

Comment: i added `glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` to the top of the display function but it didn't change anything.

Comment: i removed `glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_2D)` and the white background appeared.

Comment: @razzak: that doesn't make sense. There must have been some other issue.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of drawing

```
 void drawSquare()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    int xsize=0,ysize=0;
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {

        xsize=0;
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
             glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
               glVertex3f(-50.0+xsize, -50.0+ysize, 0.0);
               glVertex3f(-40.0+xsize, -50.0+ysize, 0.0);
               glVertex3f(-40.0+xsize, -40.0+ysize, 0.0);
               glVertex3f(-50.0+xsize, -40.0+ysize, 0.0);
            glEnd();
         xsize+=10.0;
     }
     ysize+=10.0;
     }
     glFlush();
  }
```

with glOrtho(-50.0, 50.0, -50.0, 50.0, -1.0, 1.0);[image]

Comment: You can increase the resolution(no.of grids) by increasing the value 10 in both for loops and decrease the **xsize** and **ysize** accordingly.

Comment: glBegin() and glEnd() ?